# How do i return my usb to normal

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I've been messing around with my usb, trying to make a live usb with debian on it. I used the dd command in the terminal. After multiple failures I just gave up, and I want the usb back to normal.

I tried fixing it whit the KDE partition manager, realizing that I suck with the terminal.

The manager displays the drive and the sdb1 partition on it but the file system is unknown. I can't do anything other than delete the partition.

The partition is successfully deleted and I'm left with unallocated space.

I click on "new partition", keep the settings normal, ext2 file system, and then apply changes.

Here's where the errors happen and the operation is aborted. This is the output:

Job: Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sdb1’
Command: e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sdb1
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdb1 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Check file system on partition ‘/dev/sdb1’: Error
Create a new partition (14.91 GiB, ext2) on ‘/dev/sdb’: Error

I've tried formatting to different file systems but i always get the same error, i also tried formatting it on a windows machine but with no success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install GParted:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open it, select your USB device, unmount if the case (right click on it and `Unmount`) and create a new `msdos` partition table (`Partition` menu). After that you can format it with GParted or any other tool.

Comment: thanks, it seems that gparted had no problem doing what KDE partition manager couldn't.

Comment: KDE partition manager just as Gnome Disks do not modify partition tables.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I would open command prompt with admin privileges and do:

```
diskpart
list disk
sel disk 
clean
create partition primary
format fs=fat32 label=MyDrive quick
```

On Linux, I would do:

```
dd if=/dev/zeo of=/dev/sdX bs=1M #Where X represents your usb
```

wait for a few seconds, and then send `SIGINT` by pressing `CRTL+C`
Then use gparted to create a new partition table and new partition(s)